# Android Native FB Login with Loopback.io and Passport.js?

Tags: node.js, facebook, loopbackjs

I am building a android client for my app which already has a web client and uses loopback-component-passport for FB authentication.

I am able to successfully get the access_token from FB through my Android App.

I figured out that the default passport component with loopback works by doing a GET to the callback url with Authorization Code which then gets access_token from FB. Since I already have the access_token, how can I circumvent this Authorization Code step so that I can handle the remaining logic of user creation using passport only otherwise I will have two different codes handling FB login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of passport.js doesn't have anything which will allow one to simply integrate Android Native FB login with loopback+passport.

The reason its difficult to integrate is because when one authenticates using web, the loopback endpoint of FB callback receives a authentication token which it then uses to create a access_token while in the case of native FB login through FB app, one directly gets the access_token.

The steps to integrate are as follows:

1. Setup your user model. Lets assume that you extend the standard User model from Loopback models.
2. Setup a seperate model which will store credentials that we will get
   from FB i.e. access_token, ttl etc. Lets call it FacebookAccessToken. Also setup the relationship with user model. `user.hasOne(FacebookAccessToken)` and `FacebookAccessToken.belongTo(user)`

`{
      "name": "FacebookAccessToken",
      "base": "PersistedModel",
      "idInjection": false,
      "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "FbUserId": {
          "type": "string",
          "id": true,
          "required": true
        },
        "token": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "expires": {
          "type": "date",
          "required": true
        },
        "userId": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        }
      },
      "validations": [],
      "relations": {
        "user": {
          "type": "belongsTo",
          "model": "user",
          "foreignKey": "userId"
        }
      },
      "acls": [],
      "methods": []
    }`

3. Create a custom remote method in your user model ( say loginWithFB ) which will take access_token as a parameter. Use this access token to fetch required info from facebook to create a new instance of user and save the creds in UserCredential. The following code will be in `user.js`.

NOTE - You have to set a dummy password for each user. I would suggest you to set this to something cryptic so that any one doesn't break into your system(don't forget to add some salt). Also if you are not allowing simple username password login, disable the /login endpoint

```
User.loginWithAccessToken = function (accessToken,cb) {
    FB.setAccessToken(accessToken);
    FB.api('me', function (res) {
      if(!res || res.error) {
       console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
       var err = new Error('Invalid Access Token');
       err.statusCode = 401;
       cb(err);
       return;
      }

      // accessToken is valid, so
      var query = { email : res.email};
      User.findOne({where:query}, function (err,user){
        var defaultError = new Error('login failed');
        defaultError.statusCode = 401;
        defaultError.code = 'LOGIN_FAILED';

        if(err){
          cb(defaultError);
        }else if(!user){
          // User email not found in the db case, create a new profile and then log him in
          User.create({email: query.email, password: DUMMY_PASS}, function(err, user) {
            if(err){
              cb(defaultError);
            }else{
              User.login({ email: query.email, password: DUMMY_PASS}, function(err,accessToken){
                cb(null,accessToken);
              });
            }
          });
        }
        else{
          // User found in the database, so just log him in
          User.login({ email: query.email, password: DUMMY_PASS}, function(err,accessToken){
            if(err){
              cb(defaultError);
            }else{
              cb(null,accessToken);
            }

          });
        }
      });
    });

  };

  User.remoteMethod(
    'loginWithAccessToken',
    {
      description: 'Logins a user by authenticating it with an external entity',
      accepts: [
        { arg: 'external_access_token', type: 'string', required: true, http: { source:'form'} }
      ],
      returns: {
          arg: 'accessToken', type: 'object', root: true,
          description:
            'The response body contains properties of the AccessToken created on login.\n' +
            'Depending on the value of `include` parameter, the body may contain ' +
            'additional properties:\n\n' +
            '  - `user` - `{User}` - Data of the currently logged in user. (`include=user`)\n\n'
        },
        http: {verb: 'post'}
    }

  );
```

Comment: How do you fetch user details from FaceBook in loopback ? How's the FB object created.

Answer (score 1):

you can install passport-facebook-token and add it as an entry to your providers.json like:

```
"facebook-token": {
    "provider": "facebook-mobile",
    "module": "passport-facebook-token",
    "clientID": "CLIENT_ID",
    "clientSecret": "CLIENT_SECRET",
    "callbackPath": "/auth/facebook/token",
    "failureFlash": true,
    "strategy": "FBTokenMobileStrategy",
    "json": true,
    "session": false
}
```

then you can make a call to /auth/facebook/token?access_token=PASS_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE and it will return json with the user's accesstoken from loopback and the user's userId

this will still create the UserIdentities, etc. without any additional configuration

note the "strategy" can really be any random string, because the passport-facebook-token now doesn't need the .Strategy but it's necessary to enter something here in options so that loopback-component-passport defaults to requiring the module without the .Strategy appended